# MySQL create temporary table with auto_increment id and select query

Tags: mysql, sql

want to create a temporary table that has an auto_increment field plus a field that has to be select from another table.

Here is what I have (does not work)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp  (id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
(SELECT valueName AS valueName
FROM sometable
WHERE sometable.somevalue='00'));
```

these work by them selves but can get the right syntax to do both

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp  (id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS SELECT valueName AS valueName FROM sometable
WHERE sometable.somevalue='00';
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    valueName  varchar(16) // whatever type it should be
);

INSERT INTO tmp (valueName) SELECT valueName FROM sometable WHERE ...
```

Relevant docs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Answer (score 23):

I think you might be trying to do the first case outlined here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html

..which for your example would look like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) 
SELECT valueName AS valueName FROM sometable
WHERE sometable.somevalue='00';
```

..so it might just be the parens in the wrong places that bit you in your first try.

Comment: Working nicely in one step.

Comment: Yes, works and in one step.  Probably should be the accepted answer.